# Tengo una duda/problema sobre este código, no entiendo por que funciona diferente

Tags: javascript

Una breve intro: Estoy haciendo un curso de javascript y lo que estoy haciendo ahora mismo es que cuando se haga click sobre un botón se elimine el artículo de la lista. Estoy comprobando que el id del artículo que selecciona el cliente, sea el mismo que el que se encuentra en la lista, en cuyo caso se eliminaría.

Todo funciona perfectamente, el problema es que si hacía click en el botón me eliminaba todos los artículos de lista y tras mucho tiempo, me he dado cuenta que es por este `{}` en esta línea de código.

```
const idArticulo = evento.target.getAttribute("data-id");
```

Tengo estas dos líneas de código

```
articulosAñadidos = articulosAñadidos.filter(articulo =>{
            articulo.idProducto !== idArticulo //nos muestra todos excepto los que coincida el id
        });

articulosAñadidos = articulosAñadidos.filter(articulo =>

            articulo.idProducto !== idArticulo //nos muestra todos excepto los que coincida el id
        );
```

Como bien se puede apreciar, la única diferencia entre ambas es que una tiene `{}` y la otra no. Por lo que tengo entendido (corregidme si me equivoco por favor), es que el `{}` es OPCIONAL en caso de que solamente se escriba una línea de código, si se usa más de 1, hay que ponerlo, al igual que el (), en cuyo caso solo se pone si hay más de un parámetro.
La cuestión es que la sintaxis con `{}` elimina todos los productos de la lista cuando click en el botón, mientras que la que no los tiene solamente elimina el que tu selecciones (esta es la correcta)

**¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿NO se supone que el `{}` es opcional y no debería influenciar en el resultado?**

Comment: Cuando no pones llaves en una función flecha, se devuelve el resultado de la única línea. Cuando agregas las llaves es necesario devolver el valor con `return articulo.idProducto !== idArticulo;` Ante cualquier duda, consulta la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: entendido, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si se usan lss llaves {} el return no es implícito y tienes que ponerlo
De developer mozilla:

> Las funciones flecha pueden tener un "cuerpo conciso" o el "cuerpo de bloque" habitual.
> En un cuerpo conciso, solo se especifica una expresión, que se convierte en el valor de retorno implícito.
> En el cuerpo de un bloque, debes utilizar una instrucción return explícita.

Así que en el ejemplo lo correcto si usas llaves es

```
.filter(articulo=>{return articulo.idProducto !== idArticulo});
```

Espero que te lo haya aclarado bien.

Comment: gracias me he eneterado.